# Counting how many point are in the polygon of region [R]

Tags: r, dplyr, leaflet, coordinates

I would like to ask how to calculate number of point that are in some region when we have longtitue and latitude variables of point and polygon of country and its regions.

I provided example below:
I would like to calculate how many point are in what regions (including zero when there is no point) and than add this variables to ***data2@data*** object so one can use ***count*** measures to fill each regions polygons.

```
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(101)

URL2 <- "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsp/gadm36_FRA_2_sp.rds"
data2 <- readRDS(url(URL2))


URL3 <- "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsp/gadm36_ESP_2_sp.rds"
data3 <- readRDS(url(URL3))

URL4 <- "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsp/gadm36_PRT_2_sp.rds"
data4 <- readRDS(url(URL4))

URL5 <- "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsp/gadm36_GBR_2_sp.rds"
data5 <- readRDS(url(URL5))

random_long_lat <- 
  data.frame(
    long = sample(runif(300, min = -2.5, max = 15.99), replace = F),
    lat = sample(runif(300, min = 42.69, max = 59.75), replace = F)
  )

all <- rbind(data2, data3, data4, data5)

leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
  addPolygons(data=all, stroke = TRUE, color = "black", weight="", smoothFactor = 0.95, 
              fill = F) %>% 
  addCircles(lng = random_long_lat$long, lat = random_long_lat$lat)


# Here add new variable called count, that would count how many point are in the region
all@data
```

I would like the result so one can calculate something like this:

```
all@data <- 
  all@data %>% 
  mutate(counts = rnorm(nrow(all), 100, sd = 20))

cuts <- c(0, 5, 20, 40, 80, 150, max(all@data$counts))
cuts <- colorBin("Greens", domain = all$counts, bins = cuts)

leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
  addPolygons(data=all, stroke = TRUE, color = "white", weight="", smoothFactor = 0.95, 
              fillOpacity = 0.65, fillColor = ~cuts(all$counts)) %>% 
  addLegend(pal = cuts, 
            values = all$counts,
            labFormat = labelFormat(suffix = " "),
            opacity = 0.85, title = "How many point were counted in each region", position = "topright")
```

however I dont know is it posible to calculate number of point in each regions having just coordinances?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you transform the points and France polygons to `sf` objects, you can use `st_intersects()` to count the number of points in each polygon.

Note that I updated your sample points so that each quintile break in `cuts` is unique. With your original data, the first three quintiles were just 0 so the coloring in the leaflet map didn't work.

**new sample data**

```r
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(101)

URL2 <- "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsp/gadm36_FRA_2_sp.rds"
data2 <- readRDS(url(URL2))

random_long_lat <- 
  data.frame(
    long = sample(runif(1000, min = -2.5, max = 5.99), replace = F),
    lat = sample(runif(1000, min = 42.69, max = 49.75), replace = F)
  )
```

**make sf objects and count points in polygons**

```r
library(sf)

data_sf <- data2 %>% st_as_sf()
random_long_lat_sf <- random_long_lat %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326)

data_sf_summary <- data_sf %>% 
  mutate(counts = lengths(st_intersects(., random_long_lat_sf)))
```

**define breaks for legend and draw map**

```r
cuts <- quantile(data_sf_summary$counts, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.2))
cuts <- colorBin("Greens", domain = data_sf_summary$counts, bins = cuts)

leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
  addPolygons(data=data_sf_summary, stroke = TRUE, color = "white", weight="", smoothFactor = 0.95, 
              fillOpacity = 0.65, fillColor = ~cuts(data_sf_summary$counts)) %>% 
  addLegend(pal = cuts, 
            values = data_sf_summary$hdp,
            labFormat = labelFormat(suffix = " "),
            opacity = 0.85, title = "How many point were counted in each region", position = "topright")
```

[image]

Also note that `tmap` package, which lets you switch between static and interactive maps using the same syntax (which resembles ggplot syntax).

**same map with `tmap`:**

```r
library(tmap)

tmap_mode("view") # make map interactive
tm_shape(data_sf_summary) + 
  tm_polygons(col = "counts",
              n = 5,
              palette = "Greens",
              title = "How many point were counted in each region")
```

[image]

**static map with `tmap`:**

```r
library(tmap)

tmap_mode("plot") # make map static
tm_shape(data_sf_summary) + 
  tm_polygons(col = "counts",
              n = 5,
              palette = "Greens",
              title = "How many point were counted in each region") +
  tm_layout(legend.position = c("right","top"))
```

[image]

---

**For multiple countries**

First create new sample points that cover Europe:

```
random_long_lat <- 
  data.frame(
    long = sample(runif(1000, min = -7.5, max = 19.99), replace = F),
    lat = sample(runif(1000, min = 38.69, max = 60.75), replace = F)
  )

all <- rbind(data2, data3, data4, data5)
```

Then make the sf objects and find the counts of points in every polygon:

```
all_sf <- all %>% st_as_sf()

random_long_lat_sf <- random_long_lat %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326)

all_sf_summary <- all_sf %>% 
  mutate(counts = lengths(st_intersects(., random_long_lat_sf)))

qtm(random_long_lat_sf)
```

[image]

**Option 1:** Choose maps from a list object by name using the `NAME_0` column.

```
tmap_mode("view") # make maps interactive

list_of_maps <- map(unique(all_sf_summary$NAME_0),
                    ~ tm_shape(all_sf_summary %>% 
                                 filter(NAME_0 == .x)) + # filter the data for your country of interest 
                      tm_polygons(col = "counts",
                                  n = 5,
                                  palette = "Greens",
                                  alpha = 0.85,
                                  border.col = NA,
                                  title = "How many point were counted in each region") +
                      tm_layout(legend.position = c("right","top"))) %>% 
  set_names(unique(all_sf_summary$NAME_0))

list_of_maps[['France']]
```

[image]

```
list_of_maps[['Portugal']]
```

[image]

**Option 2:** Show all the maps at once

```
### all maps at once
tm_shape(all_sf_summary) + # filter the data for your country of interest 
  tm_polygons(col = "counts",
              n = 5,
              palette = "Greens",
              alpha = 0.85,
              border.col = NA,
              title = "How many point were counted in each region") +
  tm_layout(legend.position = c("right","top")) +
  tm_facets(by = c("NAME_0"), ncol = 2, showNA = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry but point are generated mostly in the midle So way there is so small number of 0-2 clusters?

Comment: I changed the sample data b/c your leaflet code didn't work with it. When I created `cuts` with the original data, the breaks were `0, 0, 0, 0, 11`. Because the 0s were repeated, `fillColor = ~cuts(data_sf_summary$counts)` did not work.

Comment: Thank you Very Much I like leaflet tout this was a huge issue for me - you helped a lot to my research

Comment: No problem. I do want to recommend you try using `tmap` for your interactive maps. I find the syntax much easier.

Comment: Also Wanted to change is there a way hot to generaly this approach say we not only studying France, but also Spain, Porgugal, Germany, Englad at the same time - approach above will be consuming

Comment: that is issues I am trying to figure out now

Comment: @Petr, can you post some sample data for a couple countries (similar to what you did with France)?  I'll take a shot at it.

Comment: I updated the main question - thank you very mutch I have been trying to solve this for 3 days

Comment: Hey @Petr, updated the answer.  Let me know any questions.

Comment: Thank you very much - one last small question, can it be done so all countries are in one plot and not multiple? and also using leaflet preferably

Comment: Oh yeah, definitely.  Just do what we did for France, except use `all` instead of `data2`.  One note, though, the scale for the legend in that map would be aggregated for all of the countries.

Comment: Sorry but I need to bother you again, is it possible to save leaflet map as pdf? I know about `mapshot` package that allows it, but what if map is very large?

Comment: Unfortunately I’m not familiar w that. I didn’t know it was possible to have an interactive map inside a pdf. If you’re just looking for a static map - not interactive - you should try something like ggplot or tmap. That would be easier to export.

Comment: Sorry my english is bad, I wanted from interactive leaflet create static pdf,. My quenstion is how to create static pdf from large leaflet map (more than 100 mb)

Comment: Ah I see.  I am not sure about that.  Personally, I would create the static maps separately and export that.  Making an interactive map and then converting to static does not seem the best way.

Comment: thank you I will try `tmap` but it is possible to also have background in pdf that can be seen in leaflet (providers)